# Notification when servlet response received

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, servlets, notifications

I am creating reports (with `JasperReports`) in a `Java` based web application. Each report is generated by a `Servlet` and is streamed back to the user.
I have problems with reports that are sent back as attachments. (Excel reports must be sent back this way because browsers can not open Excel files). Moreover, these Excel reports take too much time to generate, therefore I open them in a new tab. Meanwhile I post an info message in the original tab. (something like "Please do not close the new tab").

The main problem is that I need to know when a report failed or succeeded. More specifically I need to know if response has been sent back and I need to know whether that response is a report or an error (right now I am sending back two different cookies). If it failed I need to show an error message, otherwise I need to remove the info message.

I have tried to use `jQuery.post()` to call the servlets but then then the download-dialog does not appear. Therefore I use `form`s. The server sends back a cookie no matter what.  On client side I am waiting for cookies and when I receive one I decide what to do. This approach works BEAUTIFULLY as desicribed in a great post [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/GruffCode/archive/2010/10/28/detecting-the-file-download-dialog-in-the-browser.aspx). 
But what approach can I take if cookies are disabled on the client side?

Comment: I don't understand this part: "I have tried to use jQuery.post() to call the servlets but then there is no download-box."  What download-box are you speaking of?

Comment: I am speaking of the download dialog that appears if the response is attachment. (I will change this part of the question)

Comment: @claymore1977: it's **not** possible to download files as attachment (showing a *Save As* dialog) using pure JavaScript/Ajax, simply because JS doesn't have any functions to show a *Save As* dialog. It has to take place using a fullworthy synchronous request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if somebody is interested in this question, here is how I finally managed to solve it. Instead of using a form to send my request to the `Servlet` I use the `window.open()` function. I open it in a new tab. Then I set an `interval` to check two things.

- if the new window is closed (`newWindow.closed`) then I know the report generated successfully
- if the `newWindow.document.readyState` is `complete` it means the report failed (because if the report fails I send back an inline response).

One advantage (in my case) of this approach (beyond that is works with cookies disabled) is that I can close the new window when an exception occurred.

**NOTE:** In IE8 after the window is closed the `newWindow.document` becomes unreachable (Permission denied). To check this I use `typeof newWindow.document != 'unknown'`.